Advection-Diffusion Equation from biased random walk
Many PDE textbooks (e.g. Logan's Applied PDEs) derive the 1D diffusion equation from a random walk on the line. As an exercise, it asked to show that the advection-diffusion equation could be derived from a biased random walk. That is, assume we have a 1D lattice with lattice spacing $\delta$ and time step $\tau$. Assume at each time, a particle moves right with probability $p$, and left with probability $1-p$. Then if we have a concentration profile $u(x,t)$, using conservation of probability we have
$$u(x,t+\tau) = p u(x-\delta,t) + (1-p) u(x+\delta,t)$$
Taylor expanding the left and right hand sides, we have:
$$u(x,t) + \tau u_t (x,t) + O(\tau^2) = u(x,t) + p \Big(-\delta u_x(x,t)+\frac{\delta^2}{2}u_{xx}(x,t)\Big) + (1-p)\Big(\delta u_x(x,t)+\frac{\delta^2}{2}u_{xx}(x,t)\Big) + O(\delta^3)$$
Therefore
$$u_t \approx \frac{\delta^2}{2\tau} u_{xx} + (1-2p) \frac{\delta}{\tau} u_x$$
However, this is a problem: the advection diffusion equation is a PDE, which is only valid in the limit $\delta,\tau \to 0$. For the derivation of the diffusion equation, $p=\frac{1}{2}$, so the first spatial derivative vanishes, and we can safely take the limit $\delta,\tau \to 0$ while keeping $\delta^2/\tau$ finite. However, here it seems we can't keep both diffusion and advection coefficients finite as space and time become continuous. How can we proceed, to end up with the PDE with both terms finite?

Let $p=\frac{1}{2}+k\delta$. See section 3 of these notes.
